# Embedding groovy.lang.GroovyShell & missing command support

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

Browsing the Groovy source there appears to be a few separate shells:

- `groovy.lang.GroovyShell`
- `groovy.ui.InteractiveShell`

The IShell class appears to have lots of commands available such as quit, help, history etc none of which are available out of the box from `g.l.GroovyShell`.

- Which should I use ?
- Is it possible to install the i-s commands into the new shell ?
- `InteractiveShell` also loads `JLine` which means it only really works from the command line.

From what I can tell I will have to copy stuff from `InteractiveShell`.

Comment: Most folks use GroovyShell, but please clarify your use case.